# How to mix-and-match inputs from two game controllers into one "virtual" controller?

Tags: windows, virtual

Image the following situation:

1. You're on Windows XP (even though the dialog shown below is a Vista screenshot).
2. You have two physical USB game controllers, let's call them A and B.
3. You have a piece of software that apparently accesses joysticks in a legacy way, only recognizing and allowing use of one single joystick.
4. When using this software, you want to use both controllers together, for instance:

   - use the left thumbstick from A and the right thumbstick from B
   - use buttons #1, #2 and #6 from A and buttons #2 and #8 from B

I guess this problem must have already popped up in hardcore gaming somewhere, and a kind of "virtual game controller driver" or other piece of software for this is available. This would ideally show up as a game controller in Windows and allow a virtual setup as described above using any inputs available on physically connected controllers to create a compound virtual one.

[image: Windows Legacy Joystick dialog]

If this is the case, I'd love to hear where to get my hands on this. And if not, any pointers on trying to get this going are welcome. I guess I'd have to read up on DirectInput and dust off my next to non-existent C++ skills then?

Like Runeborg answered, it now looks like I might have to get cracking at trying to write my own "virtual game controller device driver" if I want this to happen. :-(

Quick update: [have asked same question on smartgamer](http://smartergamer.stackexchange.com/questions/161/how-to-mix-and-match-inputs-from-two-game-controllers-into-one-virtual-controll) in the hope another crowd there might come up with an existing answer.

Comment: Too bad no more replies came in. This must be a bit too niche for SO?

Comment: I think this is probably something not many people have attempted. It's a quite interesting idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it generic to all windows applications I would imagine you have to write your own virtual game controller device driver. This [gamedev.net thread](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=296049) seems to hold a few clues. It may also be interesting to have a look at [Johnny Chung Lee's Wiimote magic](http://johnnylee.net/projects/wii/) or [the Wiimote project](http://www.wiimoteproject.com/). Johnny Chung also links to [Managed Library for Nintendo's Wiimote](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2007/03/14/1879033.aspx).

The Wii projects should contain enough information if you dig a bit to get you going. I can't really think of any other way, other than perhaps plugging in as a middleware between the application and windows somehow by intercepting messages.

Comment: Right. I was thinking exactly along the way of a virtual game controller device driver, but I was hoping something like this must have already come up and such a driver was already available somewhere. Mmm...

Comment: Due to lack of better answers, I guess I'll have to accept this one. Thanks very much, Runeborg, for the pointers you gave.

Comment: Also the Managed Library for Nintendo's Wiimote link is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Will have to look into [Total Game Control](http://www.digitaltransforms.com/index.html) to see if it could do what I would like.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't based on descriptions on the website. It's more like mapping keyboard macro's to the controls available on one controller. Haven't seen an option of using two controllers to control something; FAQ example for getting two controllers to work for multiplayer action describes running two instances of the software.

Comment: Total Game Control has quick email support, but it indeed only maps physical game controllers to keyboard macros. So it is of no use in the question scenario.